# Django: Expandable forms with fieldsets

Tags: django

I'm working with the expandable forms from here:

https://django-fieldmaker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

and I'm trying to get them to appear in my admin page. At the moment, I can only get that to happen by not using fieldsets. I can use...

```
fields = ('stuff', 'whatever')
```

...just fine, but...

```
fieldsets = [('Header',{'fields': ['stuff','whatever']}),]
```

...prevents the expandable forms from appearing. Any suggestions?

I'm not married to the idea of using the expandable forms. I have a list of resources, and I need to have a set of metadata (with optional values) for each one, *and* people have to be able to add new pieces of metadata without editing the django code, *and* every resource should be able to see all the possible pieces of metadata but not display the values that other resources have. This is proving fairly tricky. Everything I've tried so far has either not shown the metadata values, or has shown *all* the metadata values for all resources, or has been a real pain to edit.